# Expecting an absolute path error in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, kinect, processing, simple-openni

I am doing a project relating to the Kinect. I am using Processing and the code works fine. I wanted to use Eclipse instead so I installed the revelant processing tools that enable me to do this. I am using the SimpleOpenNi library and when I run the code I get the error:

```java
Exception in thread "Animation Thread" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Expecting an absolute path of the library: /SimpleOpenNI/library/win64/OpenNI2.dll
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
    at SimpleOpenNI.SimpleOpenNI.<clinit>(SimpleOpenNI.java:59)
    at ie.sign.irish.FingerTrackerKinect.setup(FingerTrackerKinect.java:23)
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2281)
    at processing.core.PGraphicsJava2D.requestDraw(PGraphicsJava2D.java:237)
    at processing.core.PApplet.run(PApplet.java:2177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have the location of the dll file in my PATH under Environment Variables and also in the folder of my project. Tried to add it to the build path to no avail.

If anyone can shed any light on this issue that would be great.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set the DLL file as native library for your SimpleOpenNI.jar

See this [tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/simple-openni/wiki/IDE).

Comment: I have this done still same error. I restarted eclipse as well still the same. I am using Windows 7 and this tutorial seems to be for MAC I am having an issue locating the Java Preferences. Is this done within Eclipse as I cannot find the path Applications/Utilities/Java Preferences.

Comment: I don't think this has to do with your Java version. Please show a screenshot of your Build Path dialog including the path to the native DLL.

Comment: It won't let me add an image as reputation too low as I only just joined the site. I have added the screenshot to my public dropbox here is the link [link]https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62320123/BUILD%20PATH.png)

Comment: Here is the screenshot of the folder path [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62320123/path.png)               I have also tried putting the folder in here that matches the error above. ie: /SimpleOpenNI/library/win64/

Comment: Ok, your setup looks good. It seems this is a bug of the library. You might want to try downloading the patched version from [here](https://code.google.com/p/simple-openni/issues/detail?id=73), and test if that works.

Comment: Still getting same thing. Might just stick with the Processing IDE, its a pity but this error is far too time consuming as I'm working towards an inflexible deadline. Thanks for your help, I'd be happy to try other things if there is a chance of fixing this.